# I do not understand how this Python code works - Unknown programming concept

Tags: python, dictionary, configparser

My apologies for the crappy headline. If I were able to frame my problem properly I would have used google ;)

I found an piece of python code able to parse ini files into a python dict called "store":

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser

def read(file, store):

    def parse_maybe(section):
        if not confp.has_section(section):
            return False

        if (section == "Main"):
            for left, right in confp.items(section):
                store[left] = right.format(**store)
        return True

    confp = SafeConfigParser()
    confp.read(file)
    parse_maybe("Main")

store = {}
store["basedir"] = "/path/to/somewhere"
read("foo.ini", store)
```

The ini files may include declarations with placeholders, for instance:

```
[Main]
output = {basedir}/somename.txt
```

When running the code, {basedir} gets replaced by "/path/to/somewhere" already defined in store. I guess this magic comes from this line of code:

```
store[left] = right.format(**store)
```

I understand *what* the code does. But I do not understand *how* this works. What is this ** operator doing with the dictionary? A pointer to a tutorial, etc. would be highly appreciated.

Comment: If that doesn't solve your query then a google search for "python double star" returned lots of other resources

Comment: **store unpacks a dictionary. If a function takes keyword arguments, and the keyword-value pairs are in a dictionary, you can pass these pairs into the functions arguments using **

Comment: @texasflood: that was the answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to my question is twofold:

1) I did not know that this is possible with format:

```
print "{a} is {b}".format(a="Python", b="great")
```

Python is great

2) Essentially the ** Operator unpacks a dictionary:

```
dict = {"a": "Python", "b": "great"}
print "{a} is {b}".format(**dict)
```

Python is great